# Possible to recover a word file embedded within a temporary internet word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, embedded, temporary-internet-files

I was emailed (in outlook) a word document that contained the instructions for a job test. The word document contained a number of other embedded word files, including a template for preparing your response. I opened the template and began preparing my response. At one point it occurred to me that I was working in a temporary internet folder and that I should save this document on my desktop so as to not lose it.

I was saving my work as I went but eventually closed the original word document that hosted the other embedded word documents (including the template). Closing that word document caused the template to close.

When I opened the document saved on my desktop, it did not contain the information I had been working on over the course of the day but only the information that was in the file when it was originally saved (like a snap shot in time). I have since realized that I only saved a copy to my desktop and that information I had saved subsequently was not being saved to that file path.

My question to the computer gods is : is it possible for me to recover the document I was working on? I have checked my temporary internet folder but it only includes the host word document (when I open the embedded template, it is as it originally was when it was sent to me).

**Please have mercy on me oh wise ones...**

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Outlook 2013 and Word 2013, don't allow you to edit the Word document launched from Outlook. It is read-only view mode and edits have to be re-saved.

Sounds like you're using an older version of Outlook. Not sure how embedded documents within a read-only document would work, but your changes would be abandoned if the Word doc was opened as read-only.

Still, method 3 & 4 might be your best bet to locate previous versions of your Word document: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316951

Also, if you have System Protection turned on, you could go to the various folder you think your file was/currently in and right click > Restore previous versions.